# How to specify the location of kml file when using geoxml3 parser with meteor js

Tags: meteor, geoxml3

I have been trying to parse a kml file using the geoxml3 parser. The geoxml3.js file is put in the public folder. The parser is working fine if I put the kml file inside the public folder.

```
geoXml.parse('doc.kml'); // this is working fine
```

But how can I make it work if the kml file is located somewhere else, say in the 'uploads' folder outside the public folder. I have tried,

```
geoXml.parse(uploadPath+'/doc.kml');
```

but this is not working. How should I specify the file path ? I can't put the kml files in the public folder as any change inside the folder will make the page refresh.

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, could not resolve the path issue. Assets.getText() is dependent on the private folder and also it doesn't stop the server from restart. But found an alternative solution, where you can upload the file to any folder within your project app and read from it.

// On client side

```
Meteor.call('getKmlString', kml_file_name, function(error, kml_string) {

        if (error) {
            console.log('ERROR in getting kml string');
            console.log(error);
        } else {
            console.log('GOT Kml String');
            geoXml.parseKmlString(kml_string);
        }

});
```

// On server side

```
Meteor.startup(function() {

    // code to run on server at startup
    return Meteor.methods({
        getKmlString: function(kml_file_name) {

            var content = '';

            var fs = Npm.require('fs');
            var encoding = encoding || 'binary';
            var chroot = Meteor.chroot || 'uploads';

            var path = chroot + (path ? '/' + path + '/' : '/');

            var content = fs.readFileSync('../../../../../' + path + kml_file_name, "utf-8", function read(err, data) {

                if (err) {
                    throw err;
                }

            });

            return content;

        },
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tried this one, but `Assets.getText()` may be what you're looking for.  The [documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#assets_getText) 
specifies that you pass it a file path relative to your `private` directory.

Comment: I have tried Assets.getText() and it is returning the file content as a string. But when I use, geoXml.parseKmlString(kml_string), kml is not showing in the map. I am getting "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getSouthWest' of undefined" error.

Comment: What does the string from `Assets.getText()` look like?  Is it in the form `"<kml>...</kml>"`?  Is an address that causes the error a specific point (street name and number), or a region?  Both?

Comment: The string does contain the "<kml>...</kml> tags, but it comes after <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

Comment: The kml contains polygon areas marked in it. I try to get the latitude and longitude of the center of each polygons.

    var lati = geoXmlDoc.gpolygons[i].bounds.getCenter().lat();
    var longi = geoXmlDoc.gpolygons[i].bounds.getCenter().lng();

Comment: any one knows a solution to this ?